# "That's how they get you."

Tags: pronombres, oraciones-impersonales

In English, I sometimes hear a conversation like this:

- A: "Watch out for those teaser rates on loans. They say 0% interest, but that's only for a short period of time."
- B: "That's how they get you."

As I understand it, B is using the word "you" impersonally, to basically mean "one." But as far as I know, one would never say "that's how they get one." So my question is:

**What would be some common ways in Spanish to say "That's how they get you.", in the above sense?**

Is there some kind of impersonal pronoun that could literally replace the word "you" in that sentence? I've seen the idea of the impersonal "se" used as a subject, like in [this example](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/se) ("Se habla Español.") and [this example](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnspanish/comments/z6pwc5/doubt_on_the_usage_of_se_era/) ("La opciones para la comunidad LGBT eran pocas: ocultar lo que se era o sufrir las consecuencias."). Maybe this or something similar can be used for objects? (I think this would be a difference from common English.) Or like how they use "a girl" in Game of Thrones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B: "Así es como **te** atrapan" (**a ti te atrapan**).

- Así es como atrapan **a uno** (a uno mismo, a una persona).
- Así es como **lo** atrapan (a usted). (Hablando de usted).
- Así **se** atrapa a la gente.
- Así es como **lo** consiguen.
- Así es como **nos** atrapan.
- Así es como funcionan (**ellos**).